# Deep Linking to retrieve authorization code

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, authorization, httprequest

I am very stuck on a problem that I have spent a lot of time on now and a lot of different trial and errors.

My app is using OAuth 2.0 in order to send an image to a vendor (Kiteworks) which is a secured storage facility. Kiteworks has its own API to allow this.

My app is launching their sign-in page, the user signs in and is redirected to the callback URL which has the authorization code in it.

What I am trying to achieve now is that once this page is hit it re-directs to my app again but most importantly it takes the authorization code with it so that I can use it to exchange for a token in order to send the image.

Here is code that I have tried which gets me as far as opening the re-direct url with my app (gives me a choice of app or chrome). What I was hoping that when I chose app then It would store the authorization code but it isn't:

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Kiteworks_SignIn"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="behind"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="sync.almacgroup.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/rest/callback">
                <!--https://sync.almacgroup.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1fb7c350-bb6a-5741-86b9-43afc2f1642f&redirect_uri=https://sync.almacgroup.com/rest/callback.html?display%3Dmobile&response_type=code&scope=&m=1&force_login=1-->
            </data>
                          />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Kiteworks sign-in activity:

```
browser = findViewById(R.id.buttonBrowser);

    browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivityForResult(browserIntent, authcode);

            if (browserIntent != null && browserIntent.getData() != null && "https://sync.almacgroup.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1fb7c350-bb6a-5741-86b9-43afc2f1642f&redirect_uri=https://sync.almacgroup.com/rest/callback.html?display%3Dmobile&response_type=code&scope=&m=1&force_login=1".equals(browserIntent.getData().getScheme())) {
                authcode  = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("code"));
                // complete oauth flow
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://sync.almacgroup.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1fb7c350-bb6a-5741-86b9-43afc2f1642f&redirect_uri=https://sync.almacgroup.com/rest/callback.html?display%3Dmobile&response_type=code&scope=&m=1&force_login=1"))
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                startActivityForResult(browserIntent, authcode);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
            authcode  = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("code"));
            Toast.makeText(this, authcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Kiteworks_SignIn.this, ex.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where im going wrong or another method to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Kling Klang any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry. I never used deep linking before.

Comment: Did you end up with a working solution ? A client asks me to connect my php app to Kitewoks but I am not sure I will be able to achieve it. I can't find examples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Your query param is `redirect_uri` not code. You need to parse the parameter named `code` after you parse `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Also i am not sure about overriding onActivityResult to get intent data. Because i've never send an Intent.ACTION_VIEW intent with startActivityForResult so i am not sure if that will work. You might need to override onNewIntent method in order to get deeplink data.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit my code to include what you have suggested? would be a big help as I am only new to this stuff!

Comment: it seems that I am not retrieving it correctly, any ideas on a better method ?